# Auto-deleting "offensive" comments is bullshit

Tags: feature-request

In particular, I alluded to [the Mike Acton presentation titled 'typical C++ bullshit'](http://macton.smugmug.com/gallery/8936708_T6zQX#593426709_ZX4pZ-L-LB).

This is the actual title of the presentation. It is known among game industry professionals by this title. If you Google things like "C++ bullshit" it is near the top of the results.

Is it possible to disable the auto-deleter, so we can talk like adults using terms adults use to describe, well, bullshit?

Comment: Perhaps a quick summary is in order, what exactly does this auto-deletion do?

Comment: @eBusiness: If a comment uses certain "profane" words - "bullshit" among them, I don't know what others - flagging it as offensive deletes it with no moderator intervention.

Answer (score 7):

Well, sometimes ideas and implementations are beyond bad. I personally find the term bullshit perfect in such cases and I think its even ridiculous to discuss it. Political correctness is much worse and harmful imo.

Another great examples are C++ compilers and linkers these days. 95% of the compiling- and linking time at my job is useless, because actually I didn't change all that stuff, but it is being recompiled and linked anyway. Mike has another great presentation about that called [Linkers suck](http://macton.smugmug.com/gallery/8966729_SSA7c#595848343_NzpGQ). You could call it just nonsense or legacy or what not, but it really *is* bullshit.

I don't know whether he is mature or not, and I don't care. I think he does a great job naming bad things in the industry. I understand Mike's words as a completely understandable anger and the desire to change such stuff and to wake up people. And of course referencing his work in comments is absolutely no need to auto-delete them, thats just ridiculous.

Needless to say, and I don't think that was Joe's point, that nobody should insult anybody here.

Answer (score -1):

I don't see the use of that term to be "talking like adults." Indeed, its use in the title of a presentation is indicative of childishness, as far as I'm concerned. The kind of "Ohh, I can insult my opposition with dirty words now!" kind of thinking. The kind that closes people's minds (I've never seen the presentation until now, and thanks to the title, I never will) rather than invites them to learn something.

Basically, the title says, "I'm smarter than you, I know what's right, and if you don't agree, then your position is @#%$." If that's the only way you have to make your arguments, then I don't see a problem with that argument not being made.

Do us game developers really feel the need to be immature about their immaturity? I know that's a sadly common thing among our games, that most M-rated games are actually quite childish and not mature at all. But **we** don't have to be that way.

Comment: The post seems more to suggest: "I'm smarter than an anti-cuss bot", which is probably correct.

Comment: I'm not sure what opposition you think Mike is insulting, and I'm not sure why you see "bullshit" as a dirty word rather than a valid categorization of some class of claims or behavior (in this case, particular design claims and compiler behavior); Harry Frankfurt's writing in this area is illuminating.

Comment: While I can see both sides of this argument, the "adult" in me says that, as an adult, I should be respectful of those around me; which in this case means not using profanity on a public forum accessible to people of all ages, cultures, and tolerances around the world.  I also do not find the use of profanity, no matter the intentions, to be professional or mature in any way; in fact, my opinion of a person who resorts to that level of communication in a public forum is quite the opposite.